# XSL Grouping not giving any result

Tags: xslt, plsql, xslt-grouping

I want to group on "zero:PosNo"
If I remove the group-commands it returns a result, but obviously it returns this:

```html
INSERT INTO RAPP_ADM.MTO_POS_IMP_TAB (PROJECT_NO, MTO_OWNER_NO, POS_NO, PART_NO, DESCRIPTION, QTY, UNIT, TOT_LEN, TOT_WEIGHT, DRAWING, GRADE, TRACE, BI_PRODUCT, SURFACE, CALC, DISCIPLINE, MADE_BY, POS_NO2, PLT_SEQ, OBJECT_SQ, OBJECT_REVISION) 
VALUES ('6111', '26-0008-R552-MOD-01-M', '1','PIP03D1160', 'PIPE sch.160 ASTM A790 UNS S31', 2.000, 'M', 2.000, 42.700, 'C097-RWP-L-XN-0057-01', 'sch.160 ASTM A790 UNS S31', 'N', '26-0008-R552-MOD-01-1', 0.559, 'N', 'L', 'sindre.thompson', '', 721, '1556750', '1');

INSERT INTO RAPP_ADM.MTO_POS_IMP_TAB (PROJECT_NO, MTO_OWNER_NO, POS_NO, PART_NO, DESCRIPTION, QTY, UNIT, TOT_LEN, TOT_WEIGHT, DRAWING, GRADE, TRACE, BI_PRODUCT, SURFACE, CALC, DISCIPLINE, MADE_BY, POS_NO2, PLT_SEQ, OBJECT_SQ, OBJECT_REVISION) VALUES 
('6111', '26-0008-R552-MOD-01-M', '1','PIP03D1160', 'PIPE sch.160 ASTM A790 UNS S31', 0.660, 'M', 0.660, 14.093, 'C097-RWP-L-XN-0057-01', 'sch.160 ASTM A790 UNS S31', 'N', '26-0008-R552-MOD-01-1', 0.184, 'N', 'L', 'sindre.thompson', '', 721, '1556750', '1');
```

```html
xmlns:zero="rosenbergverft.com:3D/2011/Zero"

   <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="no" media-type="text/plain"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
 
<xsl:for-each select="/zero:Zero/zero:MTOOwner/zero:DocumentNo/zero:BiProduct/zero:Part">
<xsl:for-each-group select="/" group-by="zero:POS_NO">
<xsl:sort select="zero:PosNo" />
INSERT INTO RAPP_ADM.MTO_POS_IMP_TAB (PROJECT_NO, MTO_OWNER_NO, POS_NO, PART_NO, DESCRIPTION, QTY, UNIT, TOT_LEN, TOT_WEIGHT, DRAWING, GRADE, TRACE, BI_PRODUCT, SURFACE, CALC, DISCIPLINE, MADE_BY, POS_NO2, PLT_SEQ, OBJECT_SQ, OBJECT_REVISION) VALUES ('
<xsl:value-of select="../../../../pdms:PDMSProject/pdms:ProjectNumber/@text" />', 
'<xsl:value-of select="zero:MtoOwnerNo" />', 
'<xsl:value-of select="zero:PosNo" />',
'<xsl:value-of select="zero:StockNo" />', 
'<xsl:value-of select="zero:Description" />', 
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="zero:Quantity/@unit = 'mm2'"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(zero:Quantity/@number div 1000000, '#0.000')"/><xsl:text>, 'M2'</xsl:text></xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="zero:Quantity/@unit = 'mm'"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(zero:Quantity/@number div 1000, '#0.000')"/><xsl:text>, 'M'</xsl:text></xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="zero:Quantity/@unit = 'pcs'"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(zero:Quantity/@number, '#0')"/><xsl:text>, 'EA'</xsl:text></xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="format-number(zero:Quantity/@number, '#0.000')"/><xsl:text>, ''</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>, 
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(zero:TotalLength/@number div 1000, '#0.000')" />, 
<xsl:value-of select="zero:TotalWeight/@number" />, 
'<xsl:value-of select="zero:DocumentNo" />', '<xsl:value-of select="zero:Grade" />', 
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="zero:Traceable/@boolean = 'false'"><xsl:text>'N'</xsl:text></xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>'Y'</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>, 
  '<xsl:value-of select="zero:BiProduct" />', 
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(zero:Surface/@number div 1000000, '#0.000')" />, 
  '<xsl:value-of select="zero:Calc" />', '<xsl:value-of select="zero:Discipline" />', 
  '<xsl:value-of select="zero:Designer" />', '<xsl:value-of select="zero:Name" />',
  <xsl:value-of select="../../../zero:PlantSeq/@number" />, '<xsl:value-of select="../../../zero:ObjectSeq/@number" />',
  '<xsl:value-of select="../../../zero:ObjectRev" />');
  </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

This is what I want to achieve:
I want the numbers on PosNo 1 to be summarized, so that it returns just one insert for PosNo 1, and not two.
The same for Posno 2, 3 etc.

```html
INSERT INTO RAPP_ADM.MTO_POS_IMP_TAB (PROJECT_NO, MTO_OWNER_NO, POS_NO, PART_NO, DESCRIPTION, QTY, UNIT, TOT_LEN, TOT_WEIGHT, DRAWING, GRADE, TRACE, BI_PRODUCT, SURFACE, CALC, DISCIPLINE, MADE_BY, POS_NO2, PLT_SEQ, OBJECT_SQ, OBJECT_REVISION) VALUES 
('6111', '26-0008-R552-MOD-01-M', '1','PIP03D1160', 'PIPE sch.160 ASTM A790 UNS S31', 2.66, 'M', 2.66, 56.793, 'C097-RWP-L-XN-0057-01', 'sch.160 ASTM A790 UNS S31', 'N', '26-0008-R552-MOD-01-1', 0.559, 'N', 'L', 'sindre.thompson', '', 721, '1556750', '1');
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Am I making any obvious mistakes?

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example, including an input, a **complete** XSLT stylesheet and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Comment: *"If I remove the group-commands it returns a result,"* Are you sure your processor supports XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I guess instead of

```
<xsl:for-each select="/zero:Zero/zero:MTOOwner/zero:DocumentNo/zero:BiProduct/zero:Part">
<xsl:for-each-group select="/" group-by="zero:POS_NO">
<xsl:sort select="zero:PosNo" />
```

you want

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/zero:Zero/zero:MTOOwner/zero:DocumentNo/zero:BiProduct/zero:Part" group-by="zero:POS_NO">
  <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
```

But is is a guess, show us your input structure and the desired result structure.

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesnt return anything.
I improved my post with better explanation of what im trying to achieve

Comment: @SindreThompson, please show the relevant XML input structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/">
```

has to be wrong, because "/" selects a single node and grouping a single node is never useful.

But without seeing the input XML, it's hard to tell you what you should have written instead.

Comment: I agree that in most contexts `<xsl:for-each-group select="/" group-by="zero:POS_NO">` does not make sense as a primary input root node is not going to several  `zero:POS_NO` but I don't agree with "grouping a single node is never useful", as XSLT's `group-by` allows to have a single item belong to several groups I have occasionally grouped a single node by a key of descendant values, for instance in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57828105/252228 I did that.

Comment: Well that's certainly innovative!